# Python - Numpy RGB pixel array to image

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have an array of pixels

```
np.shape(pred2)
Out[35]: (3000, 3, 32, 32)
```

It has 3000 images, 3 values rgb and is 32*32 in size for each image. I want to create an image from this.

Here is what I have so far:

```
img = Image.new( 'RGB', (32,32), "black") # create a new black image
pixels = img.putdata(pred2[1,:])
```

Can anyone give me a hand here as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What seems to be the problem? What output/error message do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Images are shape `(h, w, 3)`, not `(3, h, w)`. You need to permute your axes accordingly. Depending on whether you care about width vs height, it appears you can just do:

```
im = pred2[1].T
scipy.misc.imsave('the_image_file.png', im)
```